# Replaying a PCAP file with Lua script in DPDK-PKTGEN

Tags: lua, dpdk

I'm wondering how I can replay a PCAP file through a Lua script in DPDK Pktgen. When I run the load("path_to_file") command in the Pktgen command line it loads the PCAP just fine, but when attempting to do that from the Lua script I get error:
The script looks like this:

```
package.path = package.path ..";?.lua;test/?.lua;app/?.lua;"

require "Pktgen";

sendport = 0;
rate = 100;

pktgen.set(sendport, "count", 100);
pktgen.set(sendport, "rate", rate);
pktgen.load("file.pcap");
pktgen.start(sendport);
```

And the errors that I get:

```
Pktgen:/> package.path = package.path ..";?.lua;test/?.lua;app/?.lua;"

require "Pktgen";

sendport = 0;
====== Pktgen got a Segment Fault

Obtained 13 stack frames.
./usr/local/bin/pktgen(+0x34efc) [0x556cf3200efc]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x42520) [0x7fb3fa04e520]
./usr/local/bin/pktgen(+0x630f3) [0x556cf322f0f3]
./usr/local/bin/pktgen(+0x49e7a) [0x556cf3215e7a]
./usr/local/bin/pktgen(+0x79bb5) [0x556cf3245bb5].pcap");
./usr/local/bin/pktgen(+0x887b0) [0x556cf32547b0]
./usr/local/bin/pktgen(+0x79f34) [0x556cf3245f34]
./usr/local/bin/pktgen(+0x78e93) [0x556cf3244e93]
./usr/local/bin/pktgen(+0x7a2d4) [0x556cf32462d4]
./usr/local/bin/pktgen(+0x76950) [0x556cf3242950]
./usr/local/bin/pktgen(+0x73a7a) [0x556cf323fa7a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x94b43) [0x7fb3fa0a0b43]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x126a00) [0x7fb3fa132a00]
```

Anybody has encountered a similar issue?